# unable to import android projects in netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, dalvik, android-2.2-froyo

Although It works normally most of times, I am unable to import Android projects in netbeans sometimes. This is occurring frequently recently. It loads only java projects and they run well. The exception is usually one of the two:

[ExceptionInInitilizationError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html)

unable to start DalvikPlatformManager (basically a noSuchClass exception)

I though that this might be due to Android Studio which I installed recently but things did not change after uninstalling it.

Reinstalling the JRE,JDK and restarting the works sometimes but not all the times. My projects are stuck up due to this. I reinstalled the Netbeans but it didnt help.

Comment: What tools to your use in netBeans? E.g. which way do you use to import the Project?

Comment: Most of the times using import option in the IDE, and sometimes using subversion.

Comment: No, I mean do you import it as free-form project, or do you use an plugin for android development?

Comment: yes, NBAndroid Plugin.

Comment: I think that is related... Cannot comment on NBAndroid, I personally use free-form projects. If you have a build system independent of NB (`ant`, not sure if/how well others work in netBeans), you can switch to free-forms as a workaround (and to test if that really is the issue).

Comment: Well, fair enough. But free form projects might require comparatively more efforts as I guess. I think plugin is not related because it sometimes work if I reinstall JRE only and restart. How is that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36552/discussion-between-rajatiit-and-dst)

Comment: As I wrote in the chat you leaved without reacting, in your case, a class from the plugin makes issues, as the DalvikPlatformManager is part of NBAndroid. So I doubt that the JRE is the issue.

Comment: Hey ! I left chat cause you didn't reply for long. Anyway, I reinstalled just the plugin and this time it worked.I doono how but thanks for your right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete NBAndroid plugin and install it again. It looks like corrupted installation (broken JAR or something similar).